# Integration of Laplace transform

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

Is it possible to evaluate/simplify the following integral involving the Laplace transform? If yes, what are the steps or hints?
$$
I =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\,1 - \mathcal{L}_{X}\left(a \over y\right)\right]^{k} y^{b-1}\,\mathrm{d}y,
$$ where $\mathcal{L}_{X}\left(\cdot\right)$ is the Laplace transform of a positive random variable $X$.
$\quad a > 0,\ b \in \left[0, 1\right],\ $ and $\ k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I encountered this problem while calculating higher moments of a random variable. I have edited the question. I am particularly interested in calculating the Laplace transform $X$, where $X$ is a positive random variable. For example, if $X$ is the exponential random variable, we can obtain a closed-form expression.

Comment: This is still unclear. $\mathcal{L}_X(s) = \mathbb{E}[e^{-sX}]$. Then what ? What is the concrete problem you want to solve, and how did you come to this integral ?

Answer (score 0):

The Laplace transform of $\dfrac{1}{y}$ fails to exist. Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147126/laplace-transform-of-1-t) for the details

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question.  I am particularly interested in calculating the Laplace transform $X$, where $X$ is a positive random variable. For example, if $X$ is the exponential random variable, we can obtain a closed-form expression.