# How to calculate the following Laplace transform: $ \mathcal{L}[\frac{1-J_0(t)}{t}] $?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, gamma-function, bessel-functions

I'm trying to calculate the Laplace transform of this function.

$$ \mathcal{L}[\frac{1-J_0(t)}{t}] $$

where $J_0(t)$ is the zeroth Bessel function.

---

**Solution Attempt**

The p-Bessel function is defined as:
$$J_p(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+p+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+p}$$

Therefore for $p=0$ the zeroth Bessel is:
$$J_p(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+p}$$

It is trivial to prove that: 
$$\mathcal{L}\left[J_0(t)\right](s)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2 + 1}}$$

So, we have:
$$ \mathcal{L}[\frac{1-J_0(t)}{t}] = \mathcal{L}[\frac{1-\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{(m!)^2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+p}}{t}] $$

*I used $\Gamma(m+1) = m! $

Now, this looks like it could be transformed to some of the basic maclaurin series? Maybe $sin(t)$?

In any case I'm stuck at this point. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to look into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147126/laplace-transform-of-1-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$\mathcal{L}_t[F(t)](s)=f(s)$$ then: $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{F(t)}{t}\right](s)=\int_s^{\infty } f(u) \, du$$ provided: $\underset{t\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{F(t)}{t}$ exist.

Since: $$\mathcal{L}_t[1-J_0(t)](s)=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}$$ and:$$\underset{t\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{1-J_0(t)}{t}=0$$
we have:
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{1-J_0(t)}{t}\right](s)=\int_s^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\right) \, du=\ln \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{s^2}}\right)$$

Comment: You're awesome , cheers!